# How can I convert a string into a DateTime for a specific timezone, preserving the date exactly is it comes for that timezone?

Tags: java, parsing, timezone, jodatime

I have built a function that receives a date in string format and a timezone id, and transform that date in the timezone time:

```
public static DateTime transformSrcTimeInTzTime(String timeAsString, String timezoneId){
    DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID(timezoneId);
    DateTimeZone.setDefault(zone);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    DateTime tzDate = formatter.parseDateTime(timeAsString);
    System.out.println("++++ timeAsString: " + tzDate.toString(formatter));
    DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.forID(Constants.SERVER_TIMEZONE));
    return tzDate;
}
```

I don't like the part with `DateTimeZone.setDefault`; is there any way to achieve this differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the zone of the `DateTimeFormatter` itself.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID(timezoneId);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat
                      .forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
                      .withZone(zone);
DateTime tzDate = formatter.parseDateTime(timeAsString).withZone(zone);
return tzDate;
```